# How do I center 3 horizontally-arranged images on a page?

Tags: html, css, image

I have a very simple HTML/CSS webpage.

I have three images arranged horizontally on the page, like so:

[image]

I'd like to center them on the page, like so:

[image]

What's the fix?

Here's the (not-working) code I'm currently using:

```css
.sketches {
  align-content: center;
}
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="sketches">
  <img src="image1.jpg">
  <img src="image2.jpg">
  <img src="image3.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `<div>` by default is a block element and `<img>` is an inline-block  element, if you wanna center images horizontally, it's enough to set `text-align: center;` to div container:

```css
.sketches {
   text-align: center;
}

img {
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="sketches">
        <img src="image1.jpg">
        <img src="image2.jpg">
        <img src="image3.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here's the solution:**

```css
.outer {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.middle {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.sketches {
  align-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="sketches" align=center>
      <img src="image1.jpg">
      <img src="image2.jpg">
      <img src="image3.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Used technique to center vertically from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers).

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

a) `.sketches` selector

---

1) Insert `display: flex;` declaration

   2) Instead of the CSS property: `align-content` add `justify-content`

```css
.sketches {
 display         : flex;
 justify-content : center;
  
 /* can be removed */
 min-width : 350px;
}

img {
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="sketches">
        <img src="image1.jpg">
        <img src="image2.jpg">
        <img src="image3.jpg">
</div>
```